# Include sequential numbering to matching text

Tags: search, replace, grep

I have a file that currently looks like this, for example:

```
>ENSOFAS001369_p |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig204
>ENSOFAS001369_p |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig204
>ENSOFAS001264_p |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001264,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig6359
>ENSOFAS001264_p |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001264,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig6359
>ENSOFAS001369_p |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Alydus_pilosus_contig594
>ENSOFAS004569_p |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS004569,probes-probe:,probes-source:Alydus_pilosus_contig30341
```

Focusing on the portion of text between the `>` and `|` symbols, I want to add sequential numbering based on matching `ENSOFAS` numerical IDs. That is, I want to take this and make it this:

```
>ENSOFAS001369_p1 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig204
>ENSOFAS001369_p2 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig204
>ENSOFAS001264_p1 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001264,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig6359
>ENSOFAS001264_p2 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001264,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig6359
>ENSOFAS001369_p3 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Alydus_pilosus_contig594
>ENSOFAS004569_p1 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS004569,probes-probe:,probes-source:Alydus_pilosus_contig30341
```

I can grep for search in a textwrangler (>ENSOFAS(\d+)_p (.+)\r), but I know the text editor cannot do what I need to in terms of adding numbers after `_p`. I think the macOS linux version might for the search portion is `grep -E ">ENSOFAS[0-9]\{6\}_p\s|"` but don't know how to get numbering between `_p` and the white space before the `|`. Matching ENSOFAS numbers are not clustered together in the text file, but I could employ some kind of sort if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short **awk** approach:

```
awk '{ $1=$1""++a[$1] }1' file
```

The output:

```
>ENSOFAS001369_p1 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig204
>ENSOFAS001369_p2 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig204
>ENSOFAS001264_p1 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001264,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig6359
>ENSOFAS001264_p2 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001264,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig6359
>ENSOFAS001369_p3 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Alydus_pilosus_contig594
>ENSOFAS004569_p1 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS004569,probes-probe:,probes-source:Alydus_pilosus_contig30341
```

---

The alternative approach with **awk**'s `sub()` function:

```
awk '{ sub(/$/,++a[$1],$1) }1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If `awk` is an option in your setup:

```
$ awk '{cnt[$1]++; $1=$1""cnt[$1]; print}' file
>ENSOFAS001369_p1 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig204
>ENSOFAS001369_p2 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig204
>ENSOFAS001264_p1 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001264,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig6359
>ENSOFAS001264_p2 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001264,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig6359
>ENSOFAS001369_p3 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS001369,probes-probe:,probes-source:Alydus_pilosus_contig594
>ENSOFAS004569_p1 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS004569,probes-probe:,probes-source:Alydus_pilosus_contig30341
```

Explanation: `$1` will contain the first field (for each line), for example `>ENSOFAS001369_p`. We use an associative array `cnt` to count occurrences of each unique token from `$1`, and modify the field `$1` (prior output) to include the current count for the record/line processed.

The `awk` script can be shortened, but it's probably more readable and understandable in this form.